# Is the ending ~ま鶴 just a slang corruption of ~ます?

Tags: slang, internet-slang

Occasionally on Twitter, I see tweets from young native Japanese-speakers like:

> おはようございま[鶴]{つる}

with the obvious meaning of おはようございます。

Is this change of ます to まつる just a form of slang, and is it commonly used and understood?

Comment: A play on word with the old-fashioned まする, perhaps?  Not confident enough to post it as an answer.

Comment: It's not widely recognized as a piece of slang or internet meme. Maybe they're repeating what they've heard in some anime which I don't know?

Comment: I think it's just one small following on Twitter. Primarily, the posts I saw using it were from the same account (Yanakiku), a music artist. They used in a lot of their posts (YANAKIKUでございま鶴 as well as the one listed). I think it's mostly confined to the poster, and their followers. Correct me if you find any exceptions to this, but I'd guess it's just a stylistic trait of the artist rather than a common meme.

Comment: @Sqrtbottle I think you are right. I hadn't realised when I posted the question. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this seems to be just a small Twitter following. The main user, YANAKIKU, is a musician, and changing the ending of verbs to 〜ま鶴 seems to be their usage of artistic license, most likely to be cute.

I haven't seen it used anywhere other than this, so I assume the meme (if it can be called this) is really just for fans of the group.

Other examples from their twitter page include:

> おはようございま鶴♡
>   昨日はありがとうございま鶴でした！
>
> マシュー今日はありがとうございま鶴でした！マシューのMCだとなんともいえない安心感がありま鶴！
>   めっちゃかっこよかった♡
>   最後ご挨拶できなくてごめんね！これからもよろしくお願いしま鶴！
>
> おはようございまつる

Not really something I'd be able use anytime or anywhere without feeling self conscious ; )

Answer (score -2):

Commonly understood, not commonly used.  It sounds cute or annoying, depending on your personal biases.  It has no special meaning.